# Woocommerce: Dynamic Downloadable Product File

Tags: woocommerce

I am selling digital codes on my wordpress site. The product is virtual/downloadable. However, for each product purchase, I need to provide a different file for download.

For  eg. If a customer purchase an Steam Code of $50, they will get a downloadable PDF with a unique code on it (say ABCD). When the second customer purchases a $50 Steam code, they will get a new set of code (say 1234).

Currently, the woocommerce virtual/downloadable product allows me to insert a fixed file url, so every purchase will give the customer the same code. I'm trying to figure out how to go about this as I couldn't find a plugin that will allow me to put a separate downloadable file for every purchase.

I am wondering if it is possible to dynamically change the downloadable file url whenever a customer purchases the code? I can't seem to find where the file url is stored within the wordpress database so I'm not sure if the download url is product specific or if it is order specific.

Answer (score 2):

to sell digital files in this way, I suggest using plugins such as License Manager Woocommerce
It has the ability to automatically deliver the sold file or code to the customer in each purchase and replace the next one.

Two of the best plugins to do this
:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/license-manager-for-woocommerce/

https://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-license-manager/16636748